# How are hardware resources defined in Kubernetes? CPU and RAM

Tags: memory, kubernetes, cpu, scaling, ram

What is a simple explanation to resource allocation and definitions in kubernetes?
What does it mean to allocate "1000m" CPU units and 1024Mi off memory?

Answer (score 16):

(tried to write it in simpler language than the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/))

**CPU**

In Kubernetes each CPU core is allocated in units of one "milicore" meaning one Virtual Core (on a virtual machine) can be divided into 1000 shares of 1 milicore. Allocating 1000 milicores will give a pod one full CPU. Giving more will require the code in the pod to able to utilize more than one core.

**Memory**

Very simple. Each Megabyte you allocate is reserved for the pod.

**Requests**

Minimal resources that are guaranteed to be given to the pod. If there are not enough resources to start a pod on any node it will remain in "Pending" state.

**Limits**

**CPU Limit** Will cause the the pod to throttle down when hitting the limit.

**Memory Limit** When a pod utilizes all of it's memory and asks for more than the limit *it will considered a memory leak* and the pod will get restarted.

**Target** (defined in the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler)

Can be applied to CPU, Memory and other custom metrics (more complicated to define.

It's might be a good idea to set resources for a pod in sizes of **A** **B** and **C** where: A < B < C. With requests = A, Target = B and Limits = C.
Just remember that a fully loaded node might prevent pods from reaching their "target" and not never scale up.